# How to arrange elevate zoom default gallery to left side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zooming

I want arrange elevate zoom(http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples) deafult gallery below mian zoom image to left side of the image.

**My elevatezoom window is like this**

```
<img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="zoom_03" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/    radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" 
data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg"
width="411"  />

<div id="gallery_01">

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="https://raw.github.com/    elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/    elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg">
    <img src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/    elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/    master/images/large/image2.jpg">
<img src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://image.motortrend.com/f/roadtests/overview/1301_    2013_mercedes_benz_gl450_vs_2012_e350_4matic_wagon/45952740/2013-Mercedes-Benz-GL450-front-view-in-motion.j    pg" data-zoom-image="http://image.motortrend.com/f/roadtests/overview/1301_2013_mercedes_benz_gl450_vs_2012    _e350_4matic_wagon/45952740/2013-Mercedes-Benz-GL450-front-view-in-motion.jpg">
<img src="http://image.motortrend.com/f/roadtests/overview/1301_2013_mercedes_benz_gl450_vs_2012_e350_4mati    c_wagon/45952740/2013-Mercedes-Benz-GL450-front-view-in-motion.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="http://th00.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/    i/2011/040/e/5/snow_hill_tower_by_past1978-d395ezn.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://th00.deviantart.net/fs70/    PRE/i/2011/040/e/5/snow_hill_tower_by_past1978-d395ezn.jpg">
<img src="http://th00.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/i/2011/040/e/5/snow_hill_tower_by_past1978-d395ezn.jpg"     width="100"  />
</a>

<a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="images/large/image5.jpg"     data-zoom-image="images/large/image5.jpg">
<img src="images/large/image5.jpg" width="100"  />
</a>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'crosshair', galleryActiveClass: "active",     zoomType: "inner" }); 


var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
var zoomConfig = {  };
var zoomActive = false;

image.on('click', function(){

        $.removeData(image, 'elevateZoom');//remove zoom instance from image

        image.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3vMt/

I want zoom window like this